# Update function syntax error

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

Hi all so I have an update function that ends up looking like this:

```
SQL = "UPDATE Logins set Password = '" & txtPass.text & "' WHERE Username = '"
SQL = SQL & Globalvars.LoggedIn(0) & "'"
```

It's supposed to update the user's password, with txtPass being a text box on on the form, and the user's username is saved in an array called LoggedIn, in element 0.

I got the program to give the me SQL string in a msgbox and it gave me:

```
UPDATE Logins set Password = 'Egg' WHERE Username = 'Teacher'
```

Which looks correct to me. All of the fields are named correctly.

Can anyone see anything wrong with that statement?

Thanks in advance

Edit -
The code that runs:

```
Public Function RunSQL(ByVal query As String) As DataTable

    Dim Connection As New OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=Database.accdb")
    Dim DT As New DataTable
    Dim DataAdapater As OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter

    Connection.Open()
    DataAdapater = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(query, Connection)
    DT.Clear()
    DataAdapater.Fill(DT)
    Connection.Close()
    Return DT

End Function
```

I have a module that contains that function, I then in the form that has the SQL simply put

```
runSQL(SQL)
```

with "SQL" being the string generated earlier. Another example of this (that works) is:

```
    SQL = "DELETE from Students where Class = '" & GlobalVars.Code & "'"
    RunSQL(SQL)
```

That works to delete records

Comment: 1 - NEVER store your password in clear text. Use a nice hash algorithm. 2 - DON'T concatenate user input in queries, use prepared statements or whatever prevents you from SQL injections.

Comment: which rdbms are you using?

Comment: The program is just for a school project that's not going to actually be used so I'm not very concerned with storing the password, plus I don't actually know any other means. I don't concatenate in the actual program I just did that on stack overflow as it wouldn't all fit on one line otherwise. I'll edit the original post to show the complete line without the concatenation

Comment: @DatBrummie: even if it's just for a school project, what is stopping you from using the safest and best code possible? Especially in the school teacher would be proud if you wouldn't do rookie mistakes.

Comment: Still looks like concatenation to me.

Comment: @TimSchmelter I don't know any other means of doing it, I went for the not secure method I actually know how to do in this case. It's already an ambitious project

Comment: @X.L.Ant Yeah sorry I got confused I thought you meant splitting it on to two lines, my bad. What other way is there to do it without the &?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.prepare(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @DatBrummie You are still concatenating, [& is a concatenation operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/te2585xw.aspx). Use parameters! just try putting a comma in your password.

Comment: @DatBrummie: What is the error exactly? Also, you haven't shown the VB.NET code where you use this sql to update the database and where you get the error.

Comment: @X.L.Ant I think that's above me at the moment, but something I'll do more research on

Comment: @TimSchmelter I'll add the code in an edit on the original post. The error is that there is a syntax error, that pops up when the datadapater.fill line runs, however I've commented this line out and tried and the password hasn't updated

Comment: What are the details of the error you are getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Password is a reserved term in SQL and so using it in the statement causes an error.

I had to rename the field in my database and then edit the statement accordingly.